# JavaScript - Make canvas text white

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make an image with HTML5 canvas and javascript. The image has a background image and two lines of stroked text, but, the image background is empty. how can i make it White?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("Meme");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 550;
canvas.height = 545;
ctx.font = "30px Impact";
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    //ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(102, 153, 153)";
var background = new Image();
background.src = "https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Creepy-Condescending-Wonka.jpg";

// Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
background.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);
  drawText();
}
function drawText() {
ctx.strokeText("Text 1".toUpperCase() ,230,50);
ctx.strokeText("Text 2".toUpperCase() ,230,490);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Meme">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

Comment: You can stroke text in white by setting the context style to: `ctx.strokeStyle='white'`

Answer (score 1):

You should call

```
ctx.fillText(...)
```

instead of

```
ctx.strokeText(...)
```

Also you will need

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
```

Comment: and then how could i stroke the text?

Comment: @shanidahan Are you trying to stroke _and_ fill the text? What are you trying to make white? There is a background image and the text is barely visible because it is stroked and not filled. Meme-like images generally have white filled text. Can you clarify what exactly you want? A white background in the body? Or white filled text? Or stroked and filled text?